# How I can register a provider for the custom XMPP IQs with aSmack on Android

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

Anyone can me say, where or How I register a provider for the custom IQ, I using aSmack on Android, all the people talk about the register provider, but I don't know how  do that. Someone help me about, this. 
I can send and receive simple packet, it's work fine, but the problem is when I have to send  custom IQ packet than have subpackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would register a provider in Smack. The process is described here:

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html

Comment: I saw this, but I need a little example for see how I can implement that, I try many times, but my apps is break, I can receive info of packet, but I receive full null,null,null inside my packet how response :-(